# Как удалить символ из одномерного массива?

Tags: c++, массивы, char, символы

Я только недавно познакомился с массивами, поэтому и вопрос дилетантский. Итак, я разбиваю строку "Hello, World!" на символьный массив, допустим, мне нужно убрать пробел. Я думал использовать Esc-последовательность '\b', но почему-то она затирает 2 символа.

```
using namespace std;
int  main() {
    char arr[13]{ 'H','e','l','l', 'o', ',', ' ', 'W', 'o','r', 'l', 'd', '!' };
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == ' ') arr[i] = '\b';
    }
    for (j = 0; j < 13; j++) cout << arr[j];
    return 0;
}
```

После этого в консоли получается "HelloWorld!". Не понимаю, почему удалились сразу ' ' и ',' .
Подскажите пожалуйста, как универсально и эффективно затирать символы из массива?

Comment: вверху, само собой, #include <iostream> )))

Answer (score 2):

Ну смотрите, пробел вы уже убрали, так? Заменив его на backspace.

Получается, у вас Hello,<-World (<- - этот самый backspace)

Итог: выводится `Hello`, запятая, потом запятая затирается (при выводе!) и выводится `World`. Все, как вы попросили :)

А теперь - вам надо символ именно *затирать при выводе* или просто *удалять из строки*?

Comment: Теперь понял, спасибо. Не принципиально, мне крайне интересно узнать оба варианта)

Comment: Удалять - просто перекопируя то, что надо оставить, поочередно на освободившееся место. W на место пробела, o на место W и так далее...

Answer (score 2):

Есть такая функция - `memmove()`, которая умеет работать с перекрывающимися отрезками в памяти. Вот как убрать пробел в вашей строке:

```
char arr[] = "Hello, World";
memmove(arr+6,arr+7,strlen(arr+7)+1);
```